# Which type of conditional should be used in the following situation?

Tags: conditionals

I made up the situation:

My army just defeated enemy forces, but I'm not sure whether the enemy commander was killed or not. Now I say to my subordinates:

```
If their commander got killed, they won't dare to attack us again.
```

What is the correct sentence to express that meaning? Which conditional should it be?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence that was in your post

> If their commander got killed, they won't dare to attack us again.

is grammatical and idiomatic, and it has a meaning. That means it's the correct sentence to express that meaning.

If the meaning that you want has to do with the future rather than the past, you could say

> "If their commander gets killed, they won't dare to attack us again."

That is a statement about the possibility that their commander will be killed. The statement in your post was about the possibility that he has already been killed.

Comment: If my sentence is correct, then which type of conditional is it? I know your sentence is 1st conditional.

Comment: I am not familiar with the pedagogic categories of conditionals in English. Maybe someone else can help with that.